# ¿Por qué UNSIGNED ZEROFILL no me está funcionando en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

En una tabla he declarado una de sus columnas así:

```
columna INT(12) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL ...
```

En esta columna yo quiero guardar valores de 12 dígitos completos.

Si en esa columna yo intento guardar este valor:

```
010101252525
```

Lo que me guarda es el valor siguiente:

```
004294967295
```

¿Por qué no me guarda el valor `010101252525`? ¿Qué puedo hacer para guardar valores de 12 dígitos fijos, ni más ni menos?

Comment: Los necesitas para hacer alguna operación matemática o algo así?

Comment: @LuisFernando en esa columna yo guardo 6 claves de dos dígitos cada una en base a las cuales actualizo otras columnas de la tabla. O sea, esa columna es una especie de *registro de claves*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
4294967295
```

Es el máximo valor admisible por un entero de 32 bits. Lo cual es *mucha casualidad*, y nos da un indicio de por donde empezar a buscar.

Consultando la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-numeric), resulta que el tipo INT se almacena precisamente así, como un entero de 32 bits.

> Numeric Type Storage Requirements
> INT, INTEGER -> **4 bytes**

Ya vemos el origen del problema: el tipo `INT` (o `INTEGER`) usa 32 bits. El valor que intentas almacenar, `10101252525`, sencillamente **es demasiado grande**.

En la misma página de la documentación aparecen 2 posibles soluciones:

- `DECIMAL` o `NUMERIC`, que permiten almacenar números de hasta **65** dígitos.

Dicho tipo se usa indicando entre paréntesis el número de dígitos a la izquierda del punto decimal, *una coma `,`*, y el número de dígitos a la derecha del punto decimal: `DECIMAL( 12, 0 )`. Y siempre admite signo, así que `UNSIGNED` es innecesario.

- `BIGINT`, que se almacena como enteros de 64 bits (8 *bytes*).

Así pues, en tu caso podrías usar

1. `columna DECIMAL(12,0) ZEROFILL NOT NULL ...`
2. `columna BIGINT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL ...`

En el segundo caso, `UNSIGNED` sería opcional. Aun *restando* 1 *bit* de precisión, 63 *bits* dan para guardar valores **muy grandes**: hasta el `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, para ser exactos :-)

#### Otras formas

Gracias a @LuisFernando por indicar otra posible forma: guardando el valor como un `VARCHAR( )`; como si fuera una simple cadena.

Este método *desperdicia* mas espacio (1 *byte* por dígito, lo cual sería 12 *bytes* en tu caso) y dificulta su uso en comparaciones y otras operaciones, pero es una opción válida.

#### Almacenamiento

El tipo `DECIMAL` se almacena en *bloques* de 4 *bytes* por cada 9 dígitos decimales. Un `DECIMAL( 8, 0 )` ocuparía 4 *bytes*, mientras que un `DECIMAL( 12, 0 )` ocuparía 8 *bytes*.

Así pues, en tu caso, la elección de uno u otro es poco menos que inconsecuente. Tanto un `BIGINT` como un `DECIMAL( 12, 0 )` terminarán ocupando 8 *bytes* de almacenamiento cada uno.

<sub>Descendiendo a muy, muy bajo nivel, es razonable pensar que `BIGINT` será **inapreciablemente más rápido**. Cualquier máquina actual manejará valores de 64 *bits* de forma nativa, mientras que un `DECIMAL( )` puede requerir algunos cálculos adicionales, dependiendo de la implementación y de las optimizaciones internas.</sub>

Comment: Gracias. Declaré el tipo de dato como `BIGINT`... y ahora sí acepta el valor como lo quiero introducir. Resta saber qué sería mejor, si dejarlo como `BIGINT` o crear un `DECIMAL(12,0)` como comentas en la respuesta.

Comment: Incluso si no se necesita hacer calculos matematicos podrias declararlo como varchar

Comment: @A.Cedano Según la doc., viene a ser practicamente identico. BIGINT es de 64 bits, y DECIMAL(12,0) se empaqueta también en 64 bits. No deberías notar ninguna diferencia entre uno u otro.

Comment: Si te parece oportuno, para marcar el problema como resuelto, puedes editar la respuesta poniendo la posibilidad de usar `BIGINT` indicando que ambos empaquetan en 64bits, y quizá lo que sugiere @LuisFernando en su comentario, de modo que la respuesta quede más completa. Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano Editado. Me he explayado a gusto :-)

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy bien explicado. Creo que me decido por `BIGINT`. Aunque me queda una duda: dado que esa columna no se usará para cálculos, sino para almacenar seis claves de dos dígitos, ¿si declaro `VARCHAR(12)` ocuparía igualmente 1 bit por dígito? ¿O si uso `CHAR(12)`? ... No sé si esa duda sea tema para una nueva pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Fíjate que `VARCHAR` es el que mas tamaño físico requiere para guardar 12 dígitos. En general, todos los `CHAR` ocupan 1 *byte* (que no *bit* ) por carácter, como mínimo. Dependiendo de la codificación usada, incluso mas. Si con `BIGINT` te vale, úsalo.