# ¿Qué tipo de datos podría utilizar en una columna como esta en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, estructuras-de-datos

La duda vino de esta pregunta: [¿Por qué UNSIGNED ZEROFILL no me está funcionando en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105251/29967)

En una tabla tengo una columna que funciona como una especie de *almacén de claves* de dos dígitos. Es decir, en esa columna almaceno seis claves.

**Esa columna no forma parte de ningún índice en la base de datos. Tampoco hago cálculos con ella.**

**Tampoco me importa controlar los posibles errores**, no es una columna que llenarán varios usuarios, sino que tendrá sus valores fijos y me ocuparé absolutamente de que no haya errores en ellos. Yo mismo controlaré que cada columna tenga sus 12 dígitos correctamente.

**Casi siempre tendrá el mismo valor**, salvo en algunos casos, en los que su valor será cambiado por otro... Cuando el valor sea cambiado, lo será una sola vez y se usará durante todo un año. O sea, no habrá actualizaciones hasta el año siguiente.

**Esa columna siempre tendrá valores**, por lo que la cuestión de `NULL` o `NOT NULL` no tiene que ser tomada en cuenta.

Esa columna solamente me sirve para leerla en PHP y separar mis seis claves.

O sea, tomando este valor en PHP:

```
010101252525
```

Obtengo mis claves:

```
clave 1: 01
clave 2: 01
clave 3: 01
clave 4: 25
clave 5: 25
clave 6: 25
```

En la excelente respuesta de @Trauma a la pregunta señalada más arriba y sus comentarios se determinó que dicha columna puede ser declarada como:

- `BIGINT`
- `DECIMAL (12,0)`
- `VARCHAR (12)`
- `CHAR (12)`

Teniendo en cuenta lo indicado en negritas más arriba, **¿cuál sería la mejor forma de declarar dicha columna de cara al espacio que la columna va a utilizar y a la eficacia al leer/usar sus datos?**

Comment: la mejor forma es varchar(12), en cuanto a espacio en base de datos ahora en cuanto a rendimiento de consulta se usan los bigint o Decimal (este ultimo va mas enfocado a precision) mientras que el char asi no lo uses siempre te va a ocupar un espacio en memoria digamos que es una forma de reservarlo siempre

Comment: @JackNavaRow la verdad es que en cuanto a espacio, tomando en cuenta que siempre serán 12 caracteres, es `char(12)`

Comment: @Lamak si puede ser nulo ocuparia espacio por eso dije el varchar(12) pero excelente acotacion

Comment: @JackNavaRow `char` también puede ser nulo. El tema es que si siempre se usarán 12 caracteres conviene `char` porque `varchar` debe agregar 1 o 2 bytes extra para almacenar el largo del string

Comment: @Lamak olvide el tipo nuleable , es cierto o es nulo o son los 12 caracteres con el char y apoyando tu teoria aqui un enlace https://stackoverflow.com/a/15553059/5695795

Comment: De todas formas @A. Cedano, te recomendaría si es posible tener cada una de esas claves en una columna diferente. Si no se puede, entonces usar `char(12)` es lo que hace más sentido

Comment: El mínimo que puedes usar me parece que es `CHAR( 6 )`, que te ocupará 6 *bytes*. 2 dígitos son como máximo 0-99, un carácter es 0-255. El único problema es que tendrás que hacer algún calculo *extra* en _PHP_ para trabajar con los datos.

Comment: Gracias @Lamak Dado que es como una especie de columna informativa, no consideré necesario guardar cada valor en una columna aparte, la concebí como una columna que guarda metadatos, donde cada dos dígitos representan algo. En cuanto los `NULL`, la columna siempre tendrá sus 12 dígitos, no habrá nunca nulos en ella.

Comment: Creo que el mejor tipo de dato es un char(12), ya que con eso te aseguras utilizar el menos espacio en la base de datos. BigInt te reservará un gran espacio que no utilizaras por cada registro, y si el valor siempre sera doce dígitos, lo mejor es colocar un char(12), considerando que tienes todas las validaciones para que no ingresen valores no numéricos. Saludos!

Comment: Sabes de antemano cuantas filas vas a guardar en esta columna? y otra pregunta, si "Casi siempre tendrá el mismo valor" entonces no es mejor guardarlo en otra tabla, y en esta solo un puntero a ese valor?

Comment: @gbianchi en esa columna no guardaré filas... guardaré siempre un valor de 12 dígitos. Cuando afirmo que _casi siempre tendrá el mismo valor_ no me refiero a las diferentes filas de la tabla, sino a que es una columna que será poco actualizable, o sea, algunas columnas cambiarán de valor, pero no frecuentemente, sino una vez al año.

Comment: cuantas filas tiene la tabla? a eso me referia...

Comment: @gbianchi la tabla podría tener unas 2,000 filas como máximo, por el momento y tendrá varios miles de consultas por día desde la web o desde aplicaciones de Android y de iOs. La BD está alojado en un hosting compartido, por eso quiero tenerla lo más optimizada posible.

Comment: por lo que dices, 24000 bytes de datos es despreciable en comparacion a otras miles de cosas que tienes que mirar para optimizar la BD...

Comment: Según tú ¿no vale la pena entonces @gbianchi para pocos datos? De todos modos tenía curiosidad por el tema y tu respuesta y la de Trauma son muy interesantes.

Comment: no. las bases de datos son justamente para eso, para guardar datos. en el mejor formato posible obviamente, y tratando de no ocupar mas espacio del que corresponde. sin embargo, intentar una reduccion de datos tan pequeña, no se si se notaria en la BD. ten en cuenta que los datos se guardan por bloques, y no sabes como lo va a guardar la BD. Ahorrar espacio con lo conocido esta bien (no guardar un varchar de 255 para algo que ocupa 5 chars), pero tampoco pasarse.

Comment: @gbianchi me parece que tu último comentario debería aparecer como una nota en tu respuesta, de ese modo la marcaría como aceptada. Tus comentarios y los de los demás compañeros me hay ayudado a decidirme por una solución simple: `CHAR(12)` o `BIDINTEGER`.  Aunque si se tratase de millones de filas no dudaría en implementar lo planteado en tu respuesta. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yo creo que lo puedes guardar en 5 CHARS

Como bien dijiste, es una cadena de numeros. segun tu impresion una cadena de numeros de dos digitos. Asi que veamos otra forma de guardar dos digitos que sea mas barata...

Que tal si lo guardamos como binario? porque como no vas a hacer nada con eso, no importa como lo guardemos.

PhP tiene una linda funcion que se llama `decbin` que convierte un numero en binario.. en nuestro caso si probamos con el peor caso `"999999999999"` nos devuelve:

```
1110 1000  
1101 0100  
1010 0101  
0000 1111  
1111 1111
```

5 bytes! cada uno de esos bytes, los podrias transformar a un char y listo!

La vuelta es facil, PHP tiene otra linda funcion que se llama `bindec`, que hace exactamente lo mismo, recibiendo una cadena en binario.

Ahora, tenemos otro problema.. siempre tenemos que guardar 5 bytes.. Nuestro unico problema seria que toda esta cadena no empezara con un 0. justamente tu ejemplo.. veamos como resolverlo

```
decbin("010101252525") =
1001 0110
1000 0101
0011 1000
0110 1011
01
```

Lo cual es un problema.. no ocupa 5 bytes, si no que un poco menos... como lo podemos solucionar?? veamos que pasa si agregamos los 0 que faltan adelante:

```
bindec("0000001001011010000101001110000110101101");
10101252525
```

Ya se, le falta el cero adelante.. pero esto es facil, pq devuelve un numero, no un string, solo haria falta agregarle tantos 0 como caracteres falten adelante.

Entonces, tu algoritmo de conversion en español seria,

- Transformar el numero como unico a binario.
- completar con 0 hasta
- tener 40 chars.  Por cada 8 caracteres, obtener el ascii de eso
- guardar 5 caracteres ascii.

A la vuelta lo que tienes que hacer es:

- Agarrar los ascii
- transformarlos a binarios
- transformar el binario a decimal
- completar con 0 a izquierda si hay menos de 12 caracteres.

### Nota Aclaratoria:

Toda base de datos esta creada justamente para eso, para guardar datos. Los mismos deberían ser explotados (leídos, trabajados, masajeados) con la menor interacción posible. Si bien por cuestiones de espacio se puede buscar alguna clase de ahorro (sobre todo para históricos) en general en las BD se trata de que los datos estén ininmutables, eso quiere decir, en el formato que corresponde. Lo que no se debe hacer es ocupar un campo con mas datos de los necesarios. Un BIGINTEGER para guardar la edad de una persona es un desperdicio de espacio. Igual que un VARCHAR de 255 para el sexo. Es ahi donde hay que tener cuidado, hay que tener cuidado con no sobrecargar de indices por si acaso (cada indice es como otra tabla!) y hay que ajustar las tablas para que no tengan datos de mas solo por si acaso. 
Dicho esto, como solución es bonita, pero nunca la aplicaría a ningún sistema productivo, ni aunque la cantidad de registro fueran 100 Millones (100 Millones por 12 son 12 Millones de bytes.. siguen sin ser numero!)

Answer (score 5):

Lo que menos espacio de almacenamiento require es ...

```
CHAR( 6 )
```

Que, en codificaciones ISO-8859-15 u otras por el estilo, te ocupará exactamente **6 bytes**.

Tiene el *inconveniente* de que requiere cierto trabajo *extra*; para convertir un número de 2 dígitos a caracter:

```
chr( num ); // Devuelve una cadena de 1 solo caracter.
```

Para convertir un caracter a su número de 2 dígitos:

```
ord( string ); // devuelve el código del primer caracter.
```

Para convertir una cadena conteniendo 12 dígitos a su representación `CHAR( 6 )`, colocando `0` por la izquierda:

```
function encodeString( $str ) {
    $ret = '';

    $str = substr( '000000000000' . $str, 0, 12 );

    for( $idx = 0; $idx < 12; $idx += 2 )
        $ret .= chr( (int)substr( $str, $idx, 2 ) );

   return $ret;
}
```

Proceso inverso: dada una cadena de 6 caracteres, nos devuelve una cadena con los 12 dígitos correspondientes:

```
function decodeString( $str ) {
  $ret = '';

  for( $idx = 0; idx < 6; ++$idx )
    $ret .= ord( $str[$idx] );

  return ret;
}
```

**Nota** No tengo acceso a *PHP* ahora mismo, ni soy muy bueno en ese lenguaje, así que puede haber algun *errorcillo*. Espero que sirva para ilustrar la idea :-)

#### EDITO

Queremos guardar 6 grupos distintos, de 2 dígitos cada uno. Eso es equivalente a querer guardar 6 números, donde cada número puede ir del `0` al `99`.

Un carácter (depende de la codificación, pero supondremos UTF-8 ó ISO-5549) ocupa 1 *byte*. 1 *byte* puede almacenar cualquier valor entre `0` y `255`. Pensemos en que 1 *byte* es `2^8`.

Así pues, 1 solo *byte* nos sirve para guardar el rango requerido, de `0` a `99` ... ¡ y aún nos sobra !

El problema de *concepto* que estás teniendo es que 1 dígito **no es un byte**. 1 dígito se limita a 10 posibles valores: `0, 1, 2, ..., 9`.

Sin embargo, en **1 byte** caben muchos mas: `0, 1, 2, ..., 255`.

En términos *binarios*, 1 dígito cabe en `2^4` *bits*. Sin embargo, un *byte* es de 8 *bits*, por lo que le caben 2 dígitos.

También te puede confundir el tema del *empaquetado* de la base de datos. Ella asigna tamaños fijos, porque así le es mas fácil trabajar internamente. Crear y recorrer índices, trabajos internos de la CPU, ... todo ello funciona mejor con un cierto número de *bits*.

Piensa que el alfabeto son 28 letras ... pero la mayoría de las palabras **no usan todas las letras posibles**. Entonces, hacemos trampa. Si sabemos que nuestras palabras van a usar solamente 10 de las 28 posibles, podemos *optimizar* el espacio, **creando un nuevo alfabeto**. Eso es mas o menos lo que hacemos nosotros, y de ahí el hecho de necesitar funciones para *convertir* de nuestro alfabeto *privado* (de 10 letras) al alfabeto *real* de 28.

Pues parecido, pero con un alfabeto de 256 letras :-)

Comment: Pero... no entiendo el por qué de `CHAR(6)`, yo necesito almacenar un valor de 12 dígitos, con `CHAR(6)` sería imposible.

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo que se está guardando es el código de cada caracter: A es 65, B es 66, a es 97, b es 98... mira la tabla [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Yo quiero sencillamente valores parecidos a este: `010101252525` y luego obtenerlo como tal en un `SELECT` y separarlo mediante PHP en valores de dos dígitos, @PabloLozano. Quiero saber con cuál tipo de datos ocuparía menos espacio. Lo de dividirlo por PHP ya lo tengo resuelto.

Comment: @A.Cedano Con un `CHAR( 6 )`. Y, si me das suficiente tiempo, creo que podemos dejarlo en un `CHAR( 5 )`. He editado la respuesta, a ver si te aclaro algo el tema.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir y es una respuesta interesante. De hecho, había pensado en aplicar [algo parecido a esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81932/29967). Pero... ¿vale la pena el _trabajo extra_ de tener que convertir? Bueno, en realidad el trabajo de conversión sería realizado cuando toque actualizar otras columnas de la tabla, lo cual ocurre una o dos veces al año.

Comment: El tiempo de conversión es mínimo. Pero, realmente, salvo que esperes **muy muchos muchísimos** millones de registros, dudo que valga la pena. Piensa que, de todas formas, el espacio ocupado por la BBDD es difícil de controlar: *updates*, *deletes*, ... y hay que tener en cuenta el propio rendimiento de la BBDD al leer campos de longitud *rara* ... si es que ella, directamente, no lo asigna a bloques múltiplo de 4 u 8 *bytes*, con lo que todo esto no serviría absolutamente para nada :-)