# ¿Se puede saber el total de espacio que ocupa una o más columnas en todas las filas de una tabla en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, estructuras-de-datos

Traigo un dilema desde ayer con una columna de mi base de datos.

Parte del problema ha sido planteado aquí: [¿Qué tipo de datos podría utilizar en una columna como esta en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105392/29967)

He creado varias columnas con los diferentes tipos de datos y he puesto valores en ellas.

Tengo las siguientes columnas en la tabla:

```
colChar     CHAR(12)
colVarChar  VARCHAR(12)
colBigInt   BIGINT
colDecimal  DECIMAL (12,0)
```

Cada una de estas columnas tiene los mismos datos. Ninguna tiene valores nulos ni en blanco. Los datos que tiene cada una son más o menos así:

```
010101252525
```

**¿Existe alguna forma de saber el espacio total que ocupan cada una de esas  columnas en la tabla?**

**¿Sería información exacta o sería algo relativo a cuestiones como índices, número de filas, optimización de la tabla, etc**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una función Length() o su sinonimo OCTET_LENGTH() que retorna la longitud del campo en bytes.

```
SELECT campo,
        OCTET_LENGTH(campo)  'campo',

 FROM tabla
 LIMIT 10;
```

Fuente [Mysql Funcion Length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_length)